# What is the difference between "setNeedsUpdateConstraints" and "layoutIfNeeded"? When would they be called?

Tags: ios, rotation, autolayout, orientation, nslayoutconstraint

I have different values for `autolayout` constraints depending on the device orientation. I update the constraints this way:

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
   [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];

   UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

   if ((orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) || (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)) {
    self.backgroundView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"landscape.jpg"];
    [self updateLandscapeConstraints];
   }
   else if ((orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) ||
            (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)) {
    self.backgroundView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"portrait.jpg"];
    [self updatePortraitConstraints];
   }
}
```

In some posts I've seen that `[self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints]` is called after applying constraints updates, and in others `[self.view layoutIfNeeded]` is called instead. What is the difference?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:** I update constraints this way, is it correct?:

```
- (void)updateLandscapeConstraints
{
   [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

   self.passwordViewHeight.constant = 34.0;
   self.usernameViewHeight.constant = 34.0;

   [self.view removeConstraint:self.registrationButtonEqualWidth];

   self.registrationButtonEqualWidth = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.registrationButton
                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                       toItem:self.backgroundView
                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                                   multiplier:0.6
                                                                     constant:0.0];

   [self.view addConstraint:self.registrationButtonEqualWidth];

   [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you changed some conditions (like offsets or frame) which would change your constraints, call setNeedsUpdateConstraints.

> The system will then call updateConstraints as part of its normal layout pass. Updating constraints all at once just before they are needed ensures that you don’t needlessly recalculate constraints when multiple changes are made to your view in between layout passes.

If you need any of the actions after updating constraints to have immediate effect, use layoutIfNeeded after it.

So you need to call setNeedsUpdateConstraints first and once that is done you need to call layoutIfNeeded as it forces the layout of subviews before drawing, so that changed constraints reflect accordingly in the view.

Comment: Thanks. I update the `constant` property of most of my constraints depending on the device's orientation, and I create again some of the constrains I need to adjust their `multiplier`. What method is then the approppriate to be called? Or should I call both?

Comment: Calling layoutIfNeeded will be enough.